# PHP error when creating an array

Tags: php

I apologize in advance because I am very new to programming and am in a rush to get this complete as I am running on a deadline, this is also my first time using this webpage or in fact any forum.

I am required to create a simple array and loop in PHP that stores and prints the name of 3 tennis players.

My code is as follows:

```html
html>
  <head>
    <title>Tennis Players Array</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="name">
 <input type="submit" value = "submit">
</form>
    <p>
  <?php
   $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];
    if ($request == 'GET')
    {
     // Do Nothing
    }
    else if ($request == 'POST')
    {
     $TennisPlayers = array("Roger Federer", "Rafael Nadal", "Novak Djokovic");
     echo $TennisPlayers;
    }
  ?>
 </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error when I run the code:

*"Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Problem3\ProblemThree.php on line 19"*

Line 19 is

```html
echo $TennisPlayers;
```

And this is likely not going to be the only error once this one is corrected.

Look, I understand you aren't going to give me the direct answer to this and I appreciate that although I would really like some assistance in getting this to work.
P.S Sorry for such a rookie question.
Thank You! :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are trying to print `array` as `string` that why you getting this error. If you want to print `array` than used `print_r($array);` or `var_dump($array);`

Comment: echo implode(', ',$TennisPlayers);

Answer (score 2):

Its because you can't `echo` an `array` in order to print your array you need to use `print_r` or `var_dump`. But in your case you need to show the values so you can use it as

```
echo implode(',',$TennisPlayers);
```

Comment: (_FYI:You can accept or upvote an answer which helps you to solve your problem_)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print an array, you have to loop the array to get each elements:

```
foreach ( $TennisPlayers as $single_player ) {

    echo $single_player . '<br>';

}
```

This code will print:

```
Roger Federer
Rafael Nadal
Novak Djokovic
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use print_r or var_dump if you want to show the array. You can't use echo.

```
 // doesn't work
echo $TennisPlayers;

// works
var_dump($TennisPlayers);

// works
echo '<pre>';
print_r($TennisPlayers);
echo '</pre>';
```